# get all the points the line is being drawn on

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, line, points

I am drawing a line on canvas like.

```
canvas.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, paint);
```

and I want to get all the points in between Point1 and Point 2 where the line in being drawn.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the Start point is p1 and the End Point is p2 then,

Delta (change) = p1-p2

dx (change in x) =p1.x-p2.x

dy (change in y) =p1.y-p2.y

To find point P on the line use the below formula.

Find Px and Py for L varies from 0-1

Px = p1.x + L * dx

PY = p1.Y + L * dy

Comment: Thanks for reply and i want to know that L is constant here of i need to give it values from 0 to 1?

Comment: L is not a constant. It can vary from 0 to 1. For every iteration you can increase L like L=L+0.01

Comment: How did you calculate delta (p1-p2) ?